# How do I stop Safari from marking password "reused" on all sites using same LDAP

Tags: safari, password, ldap

I have a few resources that are in different domains, but all use the same LDAP authentication. So I have company.com, sceretCompanyDomain.com, companyDomainForDevTools.com, etc. Which all use same me@company.com/password LDAP login and password. All that is saved in Safari password storage.

The problem is that Safari doesn't know those are all the same account. So it puts some annoying warnings and exclamation marks to tell me that it thinks I'm reckless.

Is there a way to tell it that certain domains use the same account and not just the same password?